# Взаимодействие с цифровым тахометром СОТ-4 по RS-232

Tags: delphi, com-порт, rs232

Написали программу для снятия данных с весов, все работает, попытались подключить выше указанный тахометр и снять данных (поправив таймауты и прочее), но ничего не получили, кроме пары строк .ff .fe, хотя с весов данные аж летели, кто знает, в чем может быть причина, если надо могу выложить код настроек порта наш. Очень нужна помощь хоть какая-то.

**UPD**.

Что-то мы либо не так делаем, либо что-то еще, но порт вообще ничего не прислал нам, все пусто.
Запустили программу, аналог нашей, там есть лог с порта:

> COM3: (27/09/2011 12:30:39.31 ) Port parameters  :
>
> boudrate=9600,parity=0,bits=8,stop=0,hard_ctrl=0,soft_ctrl=0
>
> COM3: (27/09/2011 12:30:40.781) Write     1 bytes: "l"
>
> COM3: (27/09/2011 12:30:40.781) Read      4 bytes: "Ш у"
>
> COM3: (27/09/2011 12:30:40.890) Write     1 bytes: "l"
>
> COM3: (27/09/2011 12:30:40.890) Read      4 bytes: "Ш у"

И вот так очень много и все повторяется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не исключено, что для того чтобы Ваш тахометр отдавал данные в порт ему нужно отправить команду.
Смотрите документацию к устройству.

Comment: В документации, которая шла в комплекте, ничего нет. Только интерфейс через что подключаем, остальное только по поводу размеров, точности и т.д.

Comment: Write 1 bytes: "l" 

Вот это по моему и есть команда по которой ваше устройство отдает данные.
Пишите в порт "l" и смотрите что устройство ответит

Да и снифить порты предпочтительно в HEX а не в ASCII

Answer (score 1):

Причина может быть в чем угодно.

- Не тот порт открыли.
- Не те переменные смотрите.
- Не тот формат данных выбран.
- И т.п.

Обычно в таких случаях смотрят логи обращений к порту. Например, берут утилиту [portmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) и смотрят, когда и какие идут открытия и закрытия, чтения и записи в порт. После этого сверяются с тем, что должна делать программа.

Comment: Порт тот открывали точно.
Скачал ту программу, завтра после завтра посмотрю, что с её помощью можно получить, мб что-то пойдёт.
Просто непонятно в том, что вообще ни чего адекватного не получили.

Comment: Судя по тому, что порт открыт, вряд ли, но все же упомяну такой вариант: винда может перехватить порт и посчитать устройство кем-то знакомым (в моем случае идущие от радиометра данные опознавались как трекбол или что-то в этом роде), но тогда не удастся открыть порт.

Answer (score 0):

Write 1 bytes: "l"

Cделано, но тем не менее шлёт что-то непонятное. Использовали несколько вариаций (отправляли "I","II","III") получаем не более 9 байт данных.

[изображение.Jpg](http://exfile.ru/213377)

Вот ссылка на изображение, что получили в итоге. Как добавить картинку в пост не разобрался.